# Migrar Android a Phonegap

Tags: java, android, phonegap

Muchachos, tengo una duda que espero que me ayuden a resolver.

La cuestión es que si se puede migrar una aplicación de Android Studio a PhoneGap?

Espero sus respuestas, saludos.

Comment: Hola, @user7303. No parece que hayas hecho el menor esfuerzo en investigar sobre los dos entornos de desarrollo antes de realizar la pregunta. Decirte que **"sí, que todo se puede migrar si le pones suficiente empeño"**, puede que no sea la respuesta que buscas. Si lo que buscas es una comparativa de características, éste no es el sitio adecuado. Prueba primero a migrar un proyecto y luego vuelve a realizar una pregunta con las dificultades que has encontrado.

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio es un entorno de desarrollo. PhoneGap es es un framework para crear aplicaciones para móvil usando tecnología web (html + css + javascript). 
Migrar de uno a otro no tiene sentido. Puedes incluso desarrollar una aplicación PhoneGap usando como entorno Android Studio.

Si te refieres a migrar una aplicación nativa de Android a Phonegap, no hay una manera sencilla genérica.